# OWASP Java Encoder version 1.2.2 compatibility with JDK1.8

Tags: java, owasp

I need to solve XSS issues in my project that uses JDK1.8. Is OWASP Java Encoder version 1.2.2 the latest version? I could not find a higher version than this.

Comment: https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder/releases https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.encoder/encoder Yes, 1.2.2 is the latest version. Is that the answer you are looking for?

Comment: @gtiwari333 yes. Thanks